# Date String to pretty display format using PHP

Tags: php

In a database the date is stored like this `20171127` which is todays date. Unfortunately I cannot change the way the date is stored in the database.
Can I convert this string to a nice format? The excepted output is `27. November 2017`.

I already looked at [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) and [strftime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php) but there is no way to parse a string like I got.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Not sure what you've tried, but `strtotime` should work fine with that format, see https://eval.in/907457

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, use `date()` function and combine with `strtotime()`

```
date('d F Y', strtotime($yourdatehere));

//Example
<?php echo date('d F Y',strtotime('20171112')); ?>
```

The result will print `12 November 2017` & 100% tested & worked on my system.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$str = "20171127";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $str);
```

take a look here for the specifics: [datetime php manual](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php)